# What are questions do you ask to know the day of the week and the date from the Calendar?

Tags: word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Oxford dictionary has this example

[‘What day is it today?’ ‘Monday.’](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/day?q=day)

So, I guess "**What day is it?**" is used  you want to know the day of the week.

Oxford also has another example

[‘What's the date today?’ ‘The 10th.’](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/date_1?q=date)

So, I guess "**What's the date?**" is used  you want to know the day from the Calendar.

Can I say "**What date is it?**" instead of "**What's the date?**"?

Also, in the movie **Mean Girls** at 25 to 30', the guy in the movie says

"**What day is it?**" and the Girl answers "**It's October 3rd**"

**What is the logic here?**

Comment: And also [Day of the week vs. date](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/69672/2818) and [What's "What's the day?"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/220989/2818)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"What day is it?" or "What is the day today?" are both fine. Likewise, "What is the date?" or "What is the date today?" I don't recall hearing anyone say, "What date is it?" I can't point to anything wrong with that, but it's just not what people say.

If someone asked me, "What day is it?", I would answer "Monday" (or whatever day). If someone asked me, "What is the date?", I would answer, "March 11". But like any conversation, people might give answers that don't directly answer the question. Like if I asked someone, "Is Sally your girlfriend?", and he replied, "Sally is my sister", that doesn't directly answer the question but rather implies that the answer is "no". Or to take a more extreme example, if I asked, "What time is the staff meeting?" and someone replied, "The building is on fire!", that doesn't answer the question at all, but is presumably what I need to know more than the schedule time of a meeting.

Comment: It's also worth noting that people are *much* more likely to already know the current day within week than to know date within month. So even with a native Anglophone (but *especially* if you're being asked by a *learner*), if they ask *"What day is it?",* chances are they're looking for a day *number* rather than a dayname, anyway.